# How to center rotated text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the best way to center the rotated text (270deg) in current situation? It is currently position relatively but it isn't a very good solution.

HTML:

```
<div id="side" class="container">
  <p id="sidetext" >Work</p>
</div>
<div id="cont" class="container">
   <div id="row" class="row">
      Hey yeah!
   </div>
</div
```

And CSS:

```
#sidetext {
    font-family: "Josefin Sans";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 216px;
    margin: 0 22px 10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try looking at transform-origin, might help. Something like transform-origin : center center.

Comment: Seems like it might potentially work but for some reason it doesn't. I tried using both center (didn't work) and 50% (increasing the percentage for y-axis moves the text diagonally (left down) not vertically which is weird).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this css.

```css
.tab-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 2px;  /* actual text will overlap! */
    margin-top: -1px;  /* subtract half the height */
    line-height: 0px;  /* centre the text on the base line */
    text-align: center;
    left: 50%; /* added */
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg); /* added translateX */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code helped me with the right solution of this. However, I still have a small problem with it - why is the div of the text smaller (shorter than the text itself? It also slightly messes up the centered alignment. See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/A1ft9T3.png